# Статус пользователя: онлайн или оффлайн

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать статус пользователя `[on] / [off]` ? Писал я небольшой скриптик, но он постоянно выводит пользователя в онлайне.

Comment: Мне кажется, что оптимальная стратегия, это когда человек заходит на сайт помещать его в список онлайн.
Также нужно хранить время последнего обращения пользователя к любой странице сайта.  
По крону например раз в 2 минуты запускать проверку, что у всех кто в списке онлайн время последнего обращения меньше 5 минут. Если больше, то отмечать пользователя как оффлайн.

Comment: @ReinRaus, по крону? Оо

Comment: А почему бы и нет? Так без лишних заморочек будет достигнут необходимый эффект.

Comment: Эт геморой какой то :).

Comment: @ReinRaus, ИМХО, можно сделать по какому-то запросу юезра обновление. К примеру, в чате можно сделать при отправке сообщения кем-либо обновление статусов онлайн/оффлайн.

Comment: Неудивительно, что скриптец не работает =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте возьмем пример Вконтакте.ру, в онлайне человека держит около 15 минут после того, как он вышел из онлайна.

Получается следующий **алгоритм**:

**1**) При любом обращении к серверу - в таблице, где находиться данный пользователь ставиться lastvisit (timestamp).

**2**) Для проверка онлайн или нет, вытаскиваем его значение и сравниваем, когда был последний визит (к примеру, если больше 15 минут, т.е. из time() вычитаем 15 минут(timestamp) и сверяем lastvisit больше или меньше получившейся даты).

**3**) Чтобы вывести список онлайн, делаем считай тоже самое, только тянем из базы после вычитания 15 минут всех кто подходят под эти параметры.

Answer (score 2):

Тема стара как мир. Всё это реализуется с помощью сессий!
Вот [тут](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/9.html) пример.